# in JS, anArray = [] works but abArray.splice(0, anArray.length) and anArray.length=0 produce incorrect results in the following code:

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have several versions of a simple nested 'for loop' in the attached code. I'd like to reuse the same array for each iteration of the loop instead of creating a new array each iteration as apparently this used a lot of memory and creates excess garbage for collection.

The result of this code should be an array of arrays that holds a subset of a given larger array of arrays. The same simple code works differently depending on the method I use to clear an intermediate one-dimensional array within the outer loop to reuse it. Specifically, `anArray=[]`  works to clear anArray, but both `anArray.length=0` and `anArray.splice(0, anArray.length)` produce incorrect results in my code.

I know how to make this work, and I know how to code it "better". This was pulled out of functions within complex code to isolate what seems to be a bug. What I want to know is, why do the 2nd and 3rd examples not work as expected?

Disclosure: I've written lots of C and assembly doing DSP, but I'm not experienced in JavaScript. Please educate me! What knowledge am I missing that would make these results comprehensible?

If you copy the code below and paste it somewhere to run it, you'll see very clearly what happens. Please copy and run each example in isolation or they may interact and muddy the waters even more.

The code that works is this:

```js
var sets = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
] //given array of 3 arrays.
var singleSubset = []; // this simple array will hold a different subset each iteration.
var arrayOfSubsets = []; // this becomes the array of arrays that are subsets of the set arrays. 
var subsetBounds = [1, 5]; // first and last+1 indices of the subsets to be extracted.

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  singleSubset = []; // clear this array each outer iteration so we can use .push
  for (var di = subsetBounds[0]; di < subsetBounds[1]; di++) {
    singleSubset.push(sets[i][di])
  };
  arrayOfSubsets.push(singleSubset); // push each subset array on to the output array of arrays.                
}

for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  console.log(arrayOfSubsets[j]);
} // display result:

[2, 3, 4, 5]
[20, 30, 40, 50]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
```

This is as expected and correct.

Here is very similar code using .length=0 that does not work:

```js
var sets = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
] //given array of 3 arrays.
var singleSubset = []; // this simple array will hold a different subset each iteration.
var arrayOfSubsets = []; // this becomes the array of arrays that are subsets of the set arrays. 
var subsetBounds = [1, 5]; // first and last+1 indices of the subsets to be extracted.

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  singleSubset.length = 0; // clear this array each outer iteration so we can use .push
  for (var di = subsetBounds[0]; di < subsetBounds[1]; di++) {
    singleSubset.push(sets[i][di])
  };
  arrayOfSubsets.push(singleSubset); // push each subset array on to the output array of arrays.                
}

for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  console.log(arrayOfSubsets[j]);
} // display result:

[200, 300, 400, 500]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
```

This is obviously not expected and not correct.

Here is a version that avoids using .push so the intermediate array should not need to be cleared between iterations. Nevertheless, the =[] method works, and in fact is still required or this doesn't work correctly. Try this code with each of the various methods of clearing by un-commenting as needed:

```js
var sets = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
] //given array of 3 arrays.
var singleSubset = []; // this simple array will hold a different subset each iteration.
var arrayOfSubsets = []; // this becomes the array of arrays that are subsets of the set arrays. 
var subsetBounds = [1, 5]; // first and last+1 indices of the subsets to be extracted.

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  singleSubset = []; // works and is required or it doesn't work.  But comment it out and try:
  // singleSubset.length = 0;  // or try:
  // singleSubset.splice(0, singleSubset.length);  // or for extra madness try:
  // singleSubset.length = 0; singleSubset = []; // as placing .length=0 ahead of =[] produces bad output too! 
  for (var di = subsetBounds[0]; di < subsetBounds[1]; di++) {
    singleSubset[di - subsetBounds[0]] = sets[i][di];
  }
  arrayOfSubsets[i] = singleSubset;
}

for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  console.log(arrayOfSubsets[j]);
} // display result:

[200, 300, 400, 500]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
```

This is obviously not expected and not correct.

The `.length=0` preceding `=[]` option produces this:

```
[]
[]
[200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Does any of this make sense to anyone? 
I'm longing for how multi-dimensional arrays are expressed in C. So much easier to intuit!
And sure, if extracting a subset of a 2D array as a smaller 2D array can be done in one statement using better JS, I'll thank you for this too.

Comment: do you want to reuse the result array?

Comment: Not in this instance.

Comment: I'm wanting to reuse the intermediate array, which is singleSubset[]

Comment: When you do `arrayOfSubsets.push(singleSubset);` it doesn't make a copy of `singleSubset`. So all the arrays in `arrayOfSubsets` are references to the same array if you reuse the array, and any modifications you make to it affect all of them.

Comment: i still get not the purpose of this question. please highlight the problem.

Comment: @NinaScholz - To take an an array of arrays, and slice take from each subarray only the elements between the `subsetBounds`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `singleSubset = [];` you create a new array. When you use `singleSubset.length = 0;` or `singleSubset.splice(0, singleSubset.length);` you update the temp array, you've already assigned. This means that any change will be reflected on all your subsets.

In this case `singleSubset.length = 0; singleSubset = [];` you clear the previously assign array, and then generate a new one. This means that the 1st two subsets would be empty.

How I would do it - use `Array.map()` to iterate the `sets` and create a new array. Use slice on each subset, because slice returns a new array.

```js
const sets = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
]

const subsetBounds = [1, 5];

const result = sets.map(subset => subset.slice(...subsetBounds));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ori, this is very nice, thank you, I will use this and study the .map method. But this doesn't explain why singleSubset.length=0 followed by singleSubset = [] doesn't work. You'd think the singleSubset = [] would make the previous statement irrelevant.

Comment: I've updated the an answer. You push `singleSubset`, then you empty it, and the you create a new array. The result - empty subsets, except the last.

Comment: Right, of course! This just occurred to me also. Thanks much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't create a new array each time through the loop, all the elements of `arrayOfSubsets` will be references to the same array. When you change its length, splice it, or push new elements onto it, all of them get those changes.

So you either need to create a new array each time through the loop (this is the normal way) or make a copy when you push it onto the containing array:

```
arrayOfSubset.push(singleSubset.slice());
```

Comment: Thanks, okay, it must be so. So therefore right after executing the singleSubset.length=0 statement, my arrayOfSubsets[ previous iteration] goes to zero, and is then replaced with the updated singleSubset array contents, and this continues until everything is the same. Makes sense, given the idea of references  to the original as against the idea of copies. So a .slice makes a copy, but a .push creates a reference to the original. How does one learn, or 'see' which of the various methods makes a copy and which creates a reference?

Comment: You have to read the documentation of a function to find out whether it modifies the array in place or returns a new array.

Comment: In general, functions don't make copies, unless that's their specific purpose.